# MySQL Workbench rename references

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In MySQL Workbench, how do you get the "rename references" button in the schema edit tab. Clicking the edit button on one of the schemas in the schema list, or right clicking on the schema and selecting Alter Schema, brings up a dialog with the button grayed out, which apparently can change the schema name for all the tables, views, and routines.  In the Workbench [source code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/7d05cc5df2732a0fbf232f8815ec59bc738f7331/modules/db.mysql.parser/src/mysql_parser_module.cpp), there is a function named renameSchemaReferences, line 2216.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rename schema references is only available in models. All the object editors are shared between the SQL IDE and the modeling section. In a model all the DB objects are stored in an in-memory tree and can hence easily be manipulated. The mentioned function is used to update objects after a schema has been renamed (which is not possible on a MySQL server, hence for live objects the rename button is disabled).